# Constructing a ByteData view with a Uint8List throws an exception in Chrome

Tags: dart

Chrome throws an exception when constructing a ByteData from a Uint8List.

```
Uncaught TypeError: First argument to DataView constructor must be an ArrayBuffer
```

I need to use a ByteBuffer in constructing the ByteData view but ByteBuffer is an abstract class. Here are the two lines where I construct a ByteData view. This works in the VM but not Chrome.

```dart
  var buffer = new Uint8List(44);
  var view = new ByteData.view(buffer);
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried your code and it worked

> Dart VM version: 1.2.0-dev.3.0 (Fri Jan 31 02:47:34 2014) on "linux_x64"

but I think the correct way is:

```dart
var buffer = new Uint8List(44);
var view = new ByteData.view(buffer.buffer);
```

The first parameter of `ByteData.view()` is of type `ByteBuffer` and `buffer.buffer` returns a `ByteBuffer`. I don't know where the messages `ArrayBuffer` comes from.

Comment: I hunted the API for how to construct a `ByteBuffer` but my search did not succeed. Thank you for your help @Günter.